# What are the causes and remedies of constipation in toddlers?

Tags: toddler, health

My 1 1/2 year old baby daughter is having difficult with her bowel. She seems to have a constipation sensation. I have personally never seen small aged children having constipation in my life.

I like to seek guidance on the causes, cures and prevention for constipation in babies and toddlers. Thanks

Comment: hi, I was trying to analyze this topic too, but I could find the good answers. In the end, I just add schedule to eat papayas for my son regularly or my wife.

Comment: My breastfed baby started to have troubles with constipation when we started him on solids.  In retrospect, I think it may have been the mashed banana.  Also, I think the amount of dissolved minerals in the water may play a role -- in other words, the degree of "hardness" of the water.  - - -  I wouldn't worry -- some pureed stewed prunes every day will take care of it.

Answer (score 8):

Any time my daughter seems to have constipation I increase her water and offer her prunes, pears, or raisins. All of these have helped. If it is happening often, keep a food journal and talk with either the pediatrician or a nutritionist about what might be the cause. Bananas, apples, and dairy are common causes.

Answer (score 7):

The most common cause of constipation in toddlers is diet.

From WebMD:

> The culprit in many cases of toddler constipation is a diet that's too heavy in processed foods and sweets, and too light in fiber (like whole grains, fruits, and vegetables). Not getting enough fluid can also lead to constipation, because it makes the stools harder. Any change in diet -- such as when your toddler transitions from breast milk or formula to cow's milk or starts eating new foods -- can also affect the stools.

Limiting especially constipating food like cheese and bananas especially can help. Adding additional liquids (water, juice, watermelon) and high fiber foods can help. Try adding prunes or plum juice, pears, raisins, etc. At 1 1/2 using babyfood pureeed versions of some of these items may be a good option. If keeping an eye on your toddler's diet and steering it in a better direction alone is not enough to relieve chronic constipation, your pediatrician may recommend a fiber supplement or stool softener.

Answer (score 3):

My wife and I were given the advice of giving cooled boiled water (mixed with formula, if applicable). It worked for our 5 months old baby. We also have a 3 years old boy and he used to have the same trouble. We gave him water and grapes and went low on the dairy products.

Here are some great links for more information :

- http://www.babycenter.ca/a79/constipation
- http://children.webmd.com/guide/toddler-constipation-causes-treatments

Answer (score 3):

Constipation becomes difficult to remedy the longer it takes for a bowel movement to occur. You may have to use some remedies or laxatives such as glycerin to "push" it along.